# Loading Images from resource to ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to bind Image in a listView. Images are saved in Resources Dir and picking will be based on Status parameter which is get from json Array. 
I' ve found out that when it is processing, ImageConverter class is not even touched when UI is created. As a result I get listview with empty space for image and filled (as expected) labels.
Question is: How to make it work ?
And 
Is there simpler way to perform such operation

XAML FILE:

```
            <ListView x:Name="contentList"
                      RowHeight="125"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                      SeparatorColor="Black"
                      BackgroundColor="White"                         
                      ItemSelected="onOrderSelected"
                      >         
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                                             BackgroundColor="White"
                                             >
                                <Image Source="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter }}"
                                       WidthRequest="100"
                                       HeightRequest="100                                             
                                       />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                             FontSize="Default"
                                             VerticalOptions="Center"
                                             Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                             TextColor="Black"/>
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

CONVERTER:

```
class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string filename = value as string;
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(DependencyService.Get<IWRDependencyService>().GetImageBytes(filename)));
    }
}
```

Android Interface Implementation

```
class ImageLoader : IWRDependencyService
{
    public byte[] GetImageBytes(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = fileName.Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "");
        var resId = Forms.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier(
          fileName.ToLower(), "drawable", Forms.Context.PackageName);
        var icon = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Forms.Context.Resources, resId);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        icon.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, ms);
        byte[] bitmapData = ms.ToArray();
        return bitmapData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a result I get listview with empty space for image and filled (as expected) labels. Question is: How to make it work ? And Is there simpler way to perform such operation

For Converter to work in `Xamarin.Forms`, you need to declare the converter in Xaml like below:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageListViewDemo"
         x:Class="ImageListViewDemo.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:MyImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Then the converter will be triggered correctly.Here is the basic demo that I made from your codes:[ImageListViewDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/ImageListViewDemo).

Answer (score 0):

If your converter is passed the end resulting status value from your JSON you should just need to return the ImageSource according to whatever the status value is since your images are already in the resource directory.

```
 public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
 {
     var status = value as WhateverType;
     if (status == someValue1)
     {
         return ImageSource.FromFile("status1Image.png");
     }
     else if(status == someValue2)
     {
         return ImageSource.FromFile("status2Image.png");
     }
     ......
 }
```

Also if it's not going into your converter at all you might want to make sure your Converter is defined either in your App.xaml or the Resources of the Xaml file it's in.

```
<ListView.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: I did just as you said with 'ListView.Resources' , but I added local keyword to make it work so 'local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"'... Still not touching image converter and List is empty

Comment: Is the ItemsSource on your ListView being set because it doesn't look like it's being set in Xaml and you didn't post your .cs code